# No parameter encoding on MAC when filename include special characters

Tags: encoding, fine-uploader

I just found out that on a mac the URLEncoding isn't working if the filename includes special chars (Like ä / ö /...)

As you can see in the Chrome Request it's not encoded at all:

```
 Request Payload

 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui 
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datacourse" 
 25672 

 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui 
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafilename" 

 äääöööüüüßßßß 2.png 
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui 
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datacontent" 

 10 
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui 
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datasemester" 

 28 
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui 
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dataprofessor" 

 äääöööüüüßßßß 2.png 
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui 
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datadescription" 

 Descriptionäääöööüüüßßßß 2.png 
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui 
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qquuid" 

 d0b29dd3-9b9a-4583-8d5e-9f692f73917d 
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui 
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqtotalfilesize" 

 34403 
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui 
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="äääöööüüüßßßß 2.png" 
 Content-Type: image/png 


 ------WebKitFormBoundaryUQC7QNkoqSSO2qui--
```

on Windows PC the requets looks like this:

```
 Request Payload
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datacourse"

 393
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafilename"

 Ã¤Ã¼Ã¼Ã¤Ã¤Ã¼ÃŸÃŸ.jpeg
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datacontent"

 10
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datasemester"

 28
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dataprofessor"


 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datadescription"

 Description
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qquuid"

 5befc15f-f98c-4f65-b7c6-b07061dd45fa
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqtotalfilesize"

 261618
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="Ã¤Ã¼Ã¼Ã¤Ã¤Ã¼ÃŸÃŸ.jpeg"
 Content-Type: image/jpeg


 ------WebKitFormBoundaryaehKL8ARADkQle4D--
```

in the PHP endpoint i use

```
 $_REQUEST["datafilename"] = utf8_decode("datafilename"]);
```

to decode the formdate. With WIndows everything works fine. Even on Mac it's fine as long as the filename does not includes special chars (Like ä / ö /...).

If there are the output is like "a?a?a?o?o?o?u?u?u?ßß"

Any Idea what's going wrong here? Is that something I can fix in my php script. Or is it something fine uploader has to do?

As long as the Filename on Mac is clean I don't have this Problem. So looking up if OS = MAC isn't the way to go :(

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are not URL encoded.  They are already multipart encoded.  Chrome dev tools in OS X is likely using the default encoding in OS X of Mac OS Roman to display the characters in your  dev tools console.  If you are not able to properly decode the characters server-side, perhaps   you are not including the proper charset meta tag in your document.  For example, your document should include this tag:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

You can see more information about this in [a similar case a Fine Uploader user opened up](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/845) in the project's Github repo issue tracker.

Comment: Hi, but on windows Systems it's encoded. Just not on Mac. Here they say it's encoded: http://blog.fineuploader.com/2012/12/05/include-params-in-the-request-body-or-the-query-string/ adding that metatag does not change anything.

Comment: The top of that blog post lists an update that states that the parameters are no longer URL encoded as of version 3.3.  They were originally URL encoded, but that was not appropriate.  There is nothing Fine Uploader needs to do to ensure these parameters are encoded correctly.  If you are unable to decode these values server-side and you have included the proper meta tag in your document, then your server code is at fault.  You will need to ensure your server-side code is always treating the parameters as UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: And on mac it is working as long as there is no ä , ö , ü in the filename. If it is, it breaks. Without that this chars in params work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As I told before I try to decode every post parameter in php by doing $_REQUEST[name] = utf8_decode($_REQUEST[name]); Do you have an example how to do it correctly, so it works with mac as well?

Comment: I'm not very knowledgable in PHP, but the PHP man page suggests that `utf8_decode` may not be appropriate for your scenario.  If the string is already UTF-8 encoded, and your server is using UTF-8 as its default encoding, why do you feel the need to decode the string?

Comment: I need to decode because the content comes encoded. That's why it's working a windows all the time and on mac as long as no ä/ü are in the filename. If I don't do I have a UTF-8 encoded string. But when the filename has a ä / ü there is happening something different while uploading and there is an additional encoding only on mac. Let me look closer to it and come back to it later

Comment: It sounds like you may be a bit confused about encoding.  I would suggest you read the PHP man page on `utf8_decode`, along with perhaps the comments, and see what else google brings up on the topic of encoding issues server-side.  After some research, I bet this will all be a lot clearer to you.